# Having trouble impersonating WCF call to a database, displays login failed for domain\Machine$

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, windows-services, spring.net

I have a WCF service which is hosted in a windows service.
Windows service is installed and is running under Local System account.

My aim is to impersonate the caller, check if the caller has enough permissions, if he has then let him proceed, otherwise I will throw a fault exception.

DB and Windows service live on the same machine.  We are using Windows Authentication.

The app.config of the Windows service is:

```xml
<service name="ShoppingService" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior">
  <host>
    <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9900/ShoppingService"/>
    </baseAddresses>
  </host>
  <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" 
            contract="solution.IShoppingService">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost"/>
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="ShoppingServicemex" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

The behaviour is:

```xml
<behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
  <serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true"/>
</behavior>
```

The WCF implementation is:

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Allowed)]
public List<Job> GetItems()
{
    using (ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate())
    {
       string name = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
       return ItemDao.GetItems();
    }
}
```

The client connects to the service and sends request.  When I debug the WCF windows service, the value of ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity** is the caller of the service.  This is fine.

I then impersonate the `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate()`.

The trouble is that when I call the DAO `ItemDao.GetItems();` which accesses DB with the following connection: `Server=MyServer;Trusted_Connection=yes;Database=My_dev_db;`

I get the error message:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1 was unhandled by user code
  Message=Could not get ADO.NET connection.
  Source=mscorlib
Login failed for user: domain\machinename$
```

It seems to be calling the DB with the LocalSystem user account. I want to impersonate the caller each time so I check whether they have enough security permissions to call the DAO.

I am creating the client using channel factory of spring.net WCF feature.

What am I missing? Please guide?

Comment: Are you certain that WCF service and database server are on the same server?

Comment: Your're identifying against AD or smething else ? You won't to propagate the client credential to the database call ?

Comment: yes. i want the client credentials to be passed to the server, client will be an AD user

Comment: user957902, the windows service is installed on the development machine. the database lives locally.  database has no awareness of domain\machine$ account. i want it to check if the caller who is an AD account e.g. domain\userA has enough permissions to get data from DB

Comment: Scott Hanselman nailed it... It's a double hop problem. Windows authentication only works "one level down". If you need to continue passing those credentials through to lower level services, you'll need Kerberos setup. That alone can be pretty nasty, but it's the only way around the problem as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may need Kerberos in order to do this, this sounds like a classic "[Double Hop Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Double%20Hop%20Problem)."